# Unable to connect with MX record gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. with port 25 on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, smtp, amazon-ses

I am using AWS SES to send emails to users. Before sending email I want to check if the mailbox/actual email exists or not.

To check if email exists, I am using command `telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. 25` from my EC2 instance (I also tried same on my macos) to check if the port of the server is open or not, after executing the command I keep getting error of time-out, below is the output

```
Trying 74.125.24.26...
telnet: connect to address 74.125.24.26: Operation timed out
Trying 2404:6800:4003:c02::1b...
telnet: connect to address 2404:6800:4003:c02::1b: No route to host
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Comment: Is your EC2 instance running in the private subnet? do you have any NAT gateways and Internet gateways? Can you also check if you have NACLs that denies port 25 operations?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63171330/port-25-is-blocked-on-aws