# The transport failed to connect to the server in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I want to send a message but I am getting this error. Does anyone have any idea why I am getting this error?

```
On Error Resume Next
    mTo = "*****"


            mBody = "<strong>New Signup</strong><br><br> " & _
                    "Time: " & now() &  "<br><br> "

    If (mTo <> "") Then
        Set objMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
        With objMail
            .Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 ' SendUsingPort
            .Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "mail.*****.ca" ' Name or IP of remote SMTP server
            .Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 ' Server port
            .Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpConnectionTimeout") = 60
            .Configuration.Fields.Update
            .From = "Home Style - New Signup <info@******.ca>"
            .To = mTo
            .Subject = "Home Style - New Signup" 
            .HTMLBody = mBody
            .Send
        End with
        set objMail = nothing
    End If

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then

     Response.Write (Err.Description)   

     Response.End
```

Please let me know where I am missing some code.

Comment: If this is Classic ASP, then why did you tag it as ASP.NET? And why did you tag SmtpClient, which is a class in the .NET Framework?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're trying to use authentication, but you're not sending over login details.

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6500470/5544752 for more info